# How can I pass Jinja2 templated parameter to a task using the Taskflow API?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I have a task that is not correctly rendering one of its parameters if I pass it as `"{{ var.json.my_api_key.api_key }}"`:

```py
@task
def generate_signature_headers(api_key="{{ var.json.knmi_api_key.api_key }}",
         hmac_secret_key="{{ var.json.knmi_api_key.hmac_secret_key }}".encode('utf-8')):

       hmac_digest_transformed = ...some code..

        return {
            "Date": now_utc,
            "Authorization": f'Signature keyId="{api_key}",algorithm="hmac-sha512",'
            f'signature="{hmac_digest_transformed}" ',
        }
```

the api_key parameter is returned as the string `"{{ var.json.knmi_api_key.api_key }}"` without being rendered, but *hmac_secret_key* works as expected.
Everything works if I pass the api_key parameter as `Variable.get('knmi_api_key', deserialize_json=True)['api_key']` but doing so, it is going to create a connection to the metastore database every time the dag is parsed.

How can I pass the parameter with the Jinja2 templating engine?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to pass the parameters as jinja templates in @task decorated functions. Rather than that you get the `context` fields passed to it as kwarg parameters. So something like this should work:

```
@task
def generate_signature_headers(var=None):
    api_key = var.json.kmi_api_key.api_key
    hmac_secret_key = var.json.kmi_api_key.hmac_secret_key
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jarek! This is for the function definition; when calling it what should I pass as argument?

Comment: You don't call it. Task Flow API will pass context fields as kwargs when it is called.

Comment: i tried to defined the function as suggested, but when I call it by doing `signature_headers = generate_signature_headers()`, I receive a "TypeError: missing a required argument: 'var'". What could be wrong?

Comment: I think Initially I did not add = None. And just follow the Task Flow tutorial https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html I wrote it from the top of my head but you will find answers there