# jinja templates inside @task in taskflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag that does not render my jinja template:

```
@dag(default_args={"owner": "airflow"}, schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(1))
def my_dag():
    fs_hook = LocalFilesystemHook()
    
    @task
    def write_output(output_name):
        output = "This is some output."
        unique_id = "{{ ds }}_{{ ti.task_id }}_{{ ti.try_number }}"
        file_path = f"/path/to/output/{output_name}_{unique_id}.txt"
        fs_hook.write(output, file_path)
        return file_path
```

Do jinja templates work in taskflow ?

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134351/14165730)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass Jinja2 templated parameter to a task using the Taskflow API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70134140/how-can-i-pass-jinja2-templated-parameter-to-a-task-using-the-taskflow-api)

Comment: So how can I access the context of the example above? I'm not sure how to do this